Tcl: search in text file and outputs parts of the next line
I have an xml file which include these lines:
    <Integer Name="XMLVersionVal">
        <Value>16</Value>
    </Integer>

I would like to create a tcl script to find the value of the parameter XMLVersionVal in this case "16".
I've made this script (see below) which is working fine but I find it ugly and too lengthy. I would like to knew if there is a better way to do what I want. I basically look every line of the file, find the one with Name="XMLVersionVal" then remove the  and  from the next line.
Thanks for your help
set filePath "C:/tclWork/xml_file.xml"
if {[file exist $filePath]} {
    set xmlFile [open $filePath r]
    set file_content [read $xmlFile]
    close $xmlFile
    set xmlVerFound 0
    foreach {line} $file_content {
        if {[regexp {1} $xmlVerFound]} {
            regsub {<Value>} $line {} line
            regsub {</Value>} $line {} line
            set xmlVer $line
        }
    if {[string first {Name="XMLVersionVal"} $line] != -1} {
            set xmlVerFound 1
    } else {
            set xmlVerFound 0
        }
   }
}


I highly recommend to use tdom to parse XML.

I agree. tDOM is awesome for XML parsing, and you can use an XPath expression to select which node to get the value of.

For simplicity I'd recommend the following:
## just for testing
set data {Name="XMLVersionVal"> <Value>16</Value>}
regexp -nocase {Name[\r\n\f\t\s]*=[\r\n\f\t\s]*"XMLVersionVal"[\r\n\f\t\s]*>[\r\n\f\t\s]*<Value>([^<>]*)</Value>} $data dummy result
puts $result ;# prints 16

While the sequence of [\r\n\f\t\s] matches any white character = carrier return, newline, form feed, tab, space;
regexp itself returns 0 or 1 depending if a match is found.
If one knows the content to search for one could also limit to numbers which would improve liability:
regexp -nocase {Name[\r\n\f\t\s]*=[\r\n\f\t\s]*"XMLVersionVal"[\r\n\f\t\s]*>[\r\n\f\t\s]*<Value>([0-9]*)</Value>} $data dummy result

Note:
Character class changed from (.*) to ([^<>]*) which now matches any character but <>.

Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution and it doesn't work if data is the whole file. I think the regex must be changed but I'm not familiar at all with it.
Ex:
set data {
16


220
}
your code will return 16


220
Probably because it found another  later on

Thanks for the response, I improved the regexp to take care of that.

working great thanks

Good to hear. Please vote for the answer.
